# Find the value of : $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x+2)-\sqrt{x^2+6x-1}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (x+2)-\sqrt{x^2+6x-1}$$

I've tried multiplying by conjugate and dividing by $x$ but still get $0$ in the denominator.

Comment: You need to check the formatting on this question. I can't see a denominator at all. It would also help if you wrote out the work you have done, so we can check where the mistake is.

Comment: i multiplied by the conjugate and divided everything by x sorry thats where my denominator came from

Comment: wait i just found my mistake in the denominator a had a minus instead of plus giving me 1-1 in the denominator. so the answer would be -1 correct?

Comment: Typically the denominator is a sum of two otherwise-non-combinable terms.  Could you state the orginal question?

Comment: "I've tried multiplying by conjugate" Indeed this works nicely and yields the limit $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$(x+2)-\sqrt{x^2+6x-1}=\frac{-2x+5}{(x+2)+\sqrt{x^2+6x-1}}=\frac{-2+\frac{5}{x}}{(1+\frac{2}{x})+\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$

As $x$ goes to $\infty$, we have limit $-1$.

Comment: awesome thanks!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee why it's multiplication in the denominator?

Answer (score 0):

Setting $\dfrac1x=h,$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (x+2)-\sqrt{x^2+6x-1}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{1+2h-\sqrt{1+6h-h^2}}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{(1+2h)^2-(1+6h-h^2)}{h(1+2h+\sqrt{1+6h-h^2})}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{h(5h-2)}{h(1+2h+\sqrt{1+6h-h^2})}$$

As $h\to0,h\ne0;$ safely cancel out $h$

Finally set $h=0$

Comment: The calculation is not correct. In the third line, it should be $(1+2h)^2$ instead of $(1+2h)$

Comment: @JohnZHANG, Sorry for the mistake, rectified